# How a pathologist would analyse this H&E image?

Tags: cancer, pathology, staining, histopathology

I am working on a project which involves writing computer software to analyse histological images. A typical image looks like this:

[image]

It is a Hematoxylin and Eosin stained biopsy of breast cancer tissue.
Being a programmer without biology background, I would like to get insight into how a pathologist analyses such images.

More specifically:

- Which cells are cancer cells and which are regular cells?
- Can an invasive margin (a curve marking the boundary of cancer invasion into the tissue) be seen in this image?
- Can a pathologist provide a TNM classification looking at the image? If yes, what would be the T, N, M, G values for this image?

Comment: A single image is not enough for a TNM classification. This system requires knowing the size of a tumor (T), the degree of spread to new-by lymph nodes (N), as well as information about metastasis to other organs and tissues besides the lymph nodes (M), none of which are apparent from a single H & E stain image. Also, histological scoring often requires the user to scan around a slide and review many different fields of view. You'll probably want to collaborate closely with a skilled clinical pathologist for the project you've described.

Comment: @MikeyC what can be inferred from such image?

Comment: @MikeyC i.e. if a single image is not enough for classification, why is it taken?

Comment: My histology experience was looking at inflammation and necrosis in animal tissues, which is why I kept my reply to the commets section. I really only know enough about this to know that I would seek expert collaborators if I was doing what you're try to do. Histology often needs to be evaluated in context. A single image might be enough to identify cancerous or pre-cancerous cells, but you'd also need something like X-ray images to determine a T score along with additional biopsies or lab tests to determine N and M scores.

Comment: Here are some reviews I came across that might help give you a sense of similar applications being explored. 
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2910932/
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5556681/